# Should all machines which run mongo instances (mongod or mongos) in a Mongo DB cluster have unique hostnames (also at OS level)?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have been using Mongo DB Cluster for some data analysis (Mongo DB version 2.4.5) and while inserting some data into the cluster, I found an error which is the same as mentioned in the bug : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10578

My configuration is as follows:

1) Node1 - mongoconfig server, mongod shard

2) Node2 - mongoconfig server, mongod shard

3) Node3 - mongoconfig server, mongos

4) Node4 - mongos

I changed the OS hostnames of all the machines and made sure that hostnames specified in the DNS server and OS hostnames are the same. After that, the problem got solved.

But now I have a requirement that I need to add mongos instances (nodes/machines) on the fly which will have different IP addresses but the same hostname (both at the OS level and in DNS entries). I will still continue to have unique hostnames (both at OS level and in DNS entries) for all the mongo config servers and mongo shard servers.

Will that work correctly or will I run across the same problem as mentioned in the bug?

Does the requirement of unique hostnames at OS level hold true even for mongos instances or is it just for shards?

Comment: Probably belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Or maybe https://dba.stackexchange.com but definitely not here.

Comment: Agree with the comments that this belongs elsewhere, like DBA StackExchange. FYI: having duplicate active hostnames is not a server bug, it's a configuration error (particularly if those hostnames refer to different hosts in a sharded cluster). If you're spinning up new `mongos` instances on the fly they are presumably on app servers as well. In this case you could have your app servers talk to a `mongos` via `localhost` instead of changing the DNS names. You will get unpredictable results if the same `mongos` name resolves to multiple IPs for a given application/client.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that this question belonged elsewhere, thanks for pointing that out. @Stennie : Thanks for the information. I will post this question on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ShekharM Not a problem -- although to be clear, the answer is "always use unique hostnames" ;-).